# How to show list of items on button click?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am developing windows phone app..
I am taking 1 button and on click of that button the dropdown list of clothes should come..
how to code for this?

Problem: How to take this list on button click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xaml should be :

```
<Button x:Name="BtnShowCloth"  Content="showCloth" Margin="10,5" Click="BtnAddProduct_Click"/>    
<toolkit:ListPicker    ExpansionMode="FullScreenOnly"   x:Name="ClothListPicker"  Visibilty="Collapsed"   Margin="0,0,0,10"  Height="100" >
  <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource AppTextBlockStyle}" Text="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
  <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource AppTextBlockStyle}"  Text="{Binding}"  Margin="2,10,0,0" FontSize="31"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
</toolkit:ListPicker>
```

//Another way use ListBox Control

```
<ListBox  Grid.Row="1" Name="ListBoxCloth" Height="50">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource AppTextBlockStyle}"  Text="{Binding}"  Margin="2,10,0,0" FontSize="31"/>
</DataTemplate>
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Code Behind of button click fill list of cloth names. In windows phone no dropdown list exist, you should use longlistselector instead of dropdown

```
 private void BtnAddProduct_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> clothNameList = new List<string>();
        clothNameList .Add("a");
        clothNameList .Add("b");
        clothNameList .Add("c");
        clothNameList .Add("d");
        clothNameList .Add("e");
        //ClothListPicker.ItemsSource = clothNameList;
       // ClothListPicker.Visibility = Visibility.visible;
        ListBoxCloth.ItemsSource = clothNameList;
        ListBoxCloth.Height = 400;
    }
```

Comment: Ok i got it. You have to be need download toolkit from http://phone.codeplex.com/ after that add reference of that toolkit in you project.Copy/Paste  xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit" in your xaml  between <phone:PhoneApplicationPage></phone:PhoneApplicationPage> tag.

Comment: Give a look here if you add reference of Microsoft.Phone.toolkit successfully in your project http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/where-to-find-microsoft-phone-controls-toolkit-dll-in-wp-toolkit-aug-2011.

Comment: I suggest using [Nuget](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/installing-nuget) to install [WPToolkit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WPtoolkit)

Comment: @Piya Make edit in my ans. Another way to solve your problem is, use listbox instead of listpicker.

Comment: @Piya its ListBox  not toolkit:ListBox. just see my ans.

Comment: @Piya use this <ListBox  Grid.Row="1" Name="ListBoxCloth" Height="50">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource AppTextBlockStyle}"  Text="{Binding}"  Margin="2,10,0,0" FontSize="31"/>
</DataTemplate>
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>

Answer (score 1):

This is very broad question, infact does not fall in [SO standards of Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

You should research and try something and ask only if you got stuck somewhere or if your method fails.

And to your question, it needs clarification on many things like

- What is the format of your clothes data
- Are you getting it from a web service or a local db or some other resource
- Is it a single List or a groups of items etc

Hence, it becomes hard to answer. Please keep these things in mind, next time when asking questions.

Based on your comment:

You should split your task into multiple small tasks

- First thing, learn how to fetch the data from your db
- Converting that data into List of objects
- Creating your UI for the data
- Bind the data to the UI in your Button_Click event handler

Happy coding !!

Comment: Its only names of clothes like jeans shirt etc.. data is loaded in db only.. I just want to ask how to take list on button click